# How do i translate this from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, translate, internet-radio

I am unclear how to use the [Radio](https://github.com/hamedh/Radio) Icecast library in Swift. How do i translate the following into Swift?

```
radio = [[Radio alloc] init:@"my app"];
[radio connect:STREAM_URL withDelegate:self withGain:(1.0)];
playing = YES;
```

Comment: what *is* Radio? It doesn't sound like an Apple-supplied thing. Does it have a Swift Interface?

Comment: its from this project https://github.com/hamedh/Radio. No but i'm trying to work with a bridging header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that this class implemented `init` is not correct. Generally you'd see a method called `init` (which takes no parameters) and if you needed a rendition with a user agent parameter, the method would be called `initWithUserAgent:`.

So, in the `Radio.h` file, find the declaration of:

```
- (id)init:(NSString *)userAgent;
```

And replace it with:

```
- (id)initWithUserAgent:(NSString *)userAgent;
```

Do the same with the `Radio.m` file.

Then the Objective-C syntax becomes:

```
radio = [[Radio alloc] initWithUserAgent:@"my app"];
[radio connect:STREAM_URL withDelegate:self withGain:1.0];
playing = YES;
```

And the Swift equivalent would be:

```
radio = Radio(userAgent: "my app")
radio.connect(STREAM_URL, withDelegate: self, withGain: 1.0)
playing = true
```

Obviously, if this `Radio` class is implemented in Objective-C, then you'd include the .h file in your bridging header. For more information about bridging headers, see the [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77) reference.

Comment: thank you the syntax is now correct but it seems that the Radio isn't defined. I'm trying to use this component in swift https://github.com/hamedh/Radio. I'm trying to build a Icecast based radio streaming app.

Comment: It doesn't sound like `Radio.h` was added to the bridging header. When you added these files to your project, did Xcode automatically prompt you to add a bridging header? And after it did that, did you add `#import "Radio.h"` to that bridging header?

Comment: no i had to add the bridging header manually - could that be the problem? and i imported the Radio.h to the bridging header.

Comment: There are tons of articles out on the interwebs (inc. here on SO) that outline the steps for manually adding bridging header (and there are sorts of caveats about the name of the module, various project setting, etc.). Personally, I find the most fool-proof method is to add the .m and .h files again (not by adding the entire folder, but rather those six files) until I get the Xcode pop-up about adding bridging header and do it that way. But, if its telling you it cannot find `Radio`, then that would suggest a bridging header problem.

Comment: By the way, I [issued pull request](https://github.com/hamedh/Radio/pull/6) to fix the `init` method. I also tested the above syntax and it compiles fine (just confirm bridging headers and make sure you have a variables called `radio` and `playing`). I can't attest to the rest of his code (the lack of properties and the use of exposed ivars dates this codebase a bit).

Comment: Worked for me awesome - thanks! Variable playing isn't even nesscessary.